# Do I need to switch between tensorflow and numpy?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Data set is numpy set. Some tutorial said: because it is needed to in advantage of GPU, we should change numpy array to tensorflow tensor. And then use tensorflow model.

But after training, some code use numpy function to test and interactive. But the code in tensorflow official tutorial still use the same tensorflow model and tf.dataset to test.
I want to know:
When testing or real time apply, should I use numpy or tensorflow tensor and model?
In other words, is there some bad influences using tensorflow tensor and function if not traing?

eg.:
we use selected_words =tf.argsort(o_j)

in stead of

selected_words = np.argsort(o_j)

Answer (score 1):

Since TF tensor runs on GPU and numpy array runs on CPU, conversion from GPU to CPU needs memory allocation and content copy using CUDA API (see [pycuda](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html#transferring-data) document), which causes a tiny delay. Such delay could be a problem in training because of the high throughput data stream, but I think it could be ignored in most inference usage case. Anyway, if the `selected_words` is the desired output, we normally would prefer to use `tf.argsort` to make an elegant end-to-end model. However, if the output would be used in multiple places like `logits`, use `np.argsort` in a specific situation is fine.